# Javascript with xlt formatting error

Tags: javascript, xslt, formatting, padding, transformation

I'm using javascript to pad numbers in my xslt file. but when debugging I get an error saying.

> Extension function parameters or return values which have Clr type
>   'ConcatString' are not supported.

How can I fix this?

xslt

```
<xsl:template name="padNumber">
    <xsl:param name="value"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="length"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:value-of select="user:PadDigits($value,$length)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

javascript

```
function PadDigits(n, totalDigits)
{
    n = n.toString();
    var pd = '';
    if (totalDigits &gt; n.length)
    {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i&lt;(totalDigits-n.length); i++)
        {
            pd += '0';
        }
    }
    pd = pd + n.toString();
    return pd;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you can do this without the extension function using `format-number($value, substring('0000000000000000000000', 1, $length))` (add more zeros if you need to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an extension function for this at all.

**Use this pure XSLT implementation**:

```
 <xsl:template name="padNumber">
    <xsl:param name="pValue"/>
    <xsl:param name="pLength"/>

    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(substring(substring($vZeroes,1,$pLength),
                      string-length($pValue) +1),
            $pValue)
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vZeroes" select=
  "'000000000000000000000000000000000000000'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="padNumber">
    <xsl:with-param name="pValue" select="12345"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pLength" select="8"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="padNumber">
    <xsl:param name="pValue"/>
    <xsl:param name="pLength"/>

    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(substring(substring($vZeroes,1,$pLength),
                      string-length($pValue) +1),
            $pValue)
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used in this demo), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
00012345
```

**You can further parameterize the wanted padding character to be used:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vZeroes" select=
  "'000000000000000000000000000000000000000'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:call-template name="padNumber">
    <xsl:with-param name="pValue" select="12345"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pLength" select="8"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pPadChar" select="'*'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="padNumber">
    <xsl:param name="pValue"/>
    <xsl:param name="pLength"/>
    <xsl:param name="pPadChar" select="'0'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vZeroes" select="translate($vZeroes, '0', $pPadChar)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat(substring(substring($vZeroes,1,$pLength),
                      string-length($pValue) +1),
            $pValue)
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is performed, the result is now:**

```
***12345
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your PadDigits to return strings:

```
return "" + pd;
```

Answer (score 0):

@RoManiac thank that helps. I found this template that I prefer just incase anyone comes and looks later.

```
<xsl:template name="format-batchnum">
    <xsl:param name="batchnum"/>
    <xsl:param name="numbatchdigit" select="12"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($batchnum)>=$numbatchdigit">
        <xsl:value-of select="$batchnum"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="format-batchnum">
          <xsl:with-param name="batchnum" select="$batchnum"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="numbatchdigit" select="$numbatchdigit -1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```